# Best way to loop through a filtered pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I need to loop through a pandas DataFrame, but first I have to filter it. I need to look at how many "old_id"s are attached to each new ID.

I wrote this code and is working fine, but it doesn't scale really well.

```
d = dict()

for new_id in (new_id_list):
    
    d[new_id] = df[df['new_id_col'] == new_id]['old_id'].nunique()
```

How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: You might not need to loop at all.   Can you post a small dataset with expected outputs?   I think this can be done differently without looping.

Comment: @ScottBoston I have a feeling this can be done with a groupby, but i'll let you take this one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for `groupby` + `nunique`. This fetches the number of unique "old_id"s per "new_id_col":

```
out = df.groupby('new_id_col')['old_id'].nunique().to_dict()
```

Comment: Simply a genius! Now that you pointed out, the loop is meaningless... the path of the code is always tricky...